Duality in Linear Semi-Infinite Programming
I am trying to understand the dual for a linear semi-infinite program and I found more than one definition but cannot figure out why they should be the same. The primal linear program is the following:
Let $B$ be an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, $a: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, b: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, c \in \mathbb{R}^n$. $$\text{sup}_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n} c^Tz$$ $$\text{where }~~~~a^T(t)z \leq b(t)~~~~\forall t \in B$$
The first dual formulation ($D$) is from https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1035089 which says the following:
$$\text{inf}_{\mu \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{(B)}} \sum_{t \in B} b(t)\mu(t)$$
$$\text{where }~~~~\sum_{t \in B} a(t)\mu(t) = c$$
where $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{(B)}$ is the set of non-negative Borel measures on $B$ with finite support. They then state that if $B$ is a compact set and $a,b$ are continuous on $B$, then due to a theorem of Rogosinsky, the following dual in measure space ($D_M$) achieves the same optimal value as ($D$):
$$\text{inf}_{\mu \in M^{+}(B)} \int_{B} b(t)d\mu(t)$$
$$\text{where }~~~~\int_{B} a(t)d\mu(t) = c$$
where $M^{+}(B)$ is the set of non-negative Borel measures on $B$.
The second dual formulation ($D'$) is from https://ise.ncsu.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2018/10/LSIP-SIAM.pdf which says the following:
$$\text{inf}_{x(t) \in L_1^{+}(B, \lambda)} \int_{B} b(t)x(t)d\lambda(t)$$
$$\text{where }~~~~\int_{B} a(t)x(t)d\lambda(t) = c$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, $L_1^{+}(B, \lambda)$ is the set of functions $x(t)$ which are measurable on $B$, non-negative a.e wrt $\lambda$ and $\int_B x(t)d\lambda(t)$ is finite.
I understand that a finite non-negative Borel measure $\mu$ on a compact set is regular, and integration wrt to $\mu$ corresponds to Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral wrt $F_{\mu}$. In addition, if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous wrt $\lambda$, then the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral will correspond to an integration wrt $x(t)d\lambda(t)$ where $x(t)$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ wrt $\lambda$. But if $\mu$ is a measure with finite support, it will not be absolutely continuous wrt $\lambda$, and there should be an absolutely continuous component, a singular continuous component and a pure point component. So I do not understand how ($D_M$) and ($D'$) are the same/equivalent dual program, or what is the connection between the two.
